# How to add JTextField into JScrollPane Dynamically?

Tags: java, swing

I add these of code and nothing show in my swing scroll pane
 int rowCnt = 1, i, j;

```
for (i = 0; i < rowCnt; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < rowCnt + 7; j++) {
        myJTextField txt = new myJTextField();
        txt.setBounds(35, 10, 200, 25);
        scrPaneTextField.add(txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't add components to a scroll pane, use a JPanel as the view for the scroll pane and add your components to it. Also, make use of appropriate layout managers

Comment: See also [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `setBounds()` method. This implies you are using a null layout which you should not be doing. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of components.

Looks like you have a grid of components.

Add your components to a panel using a `GridLayout`. Then add the panel to the scrollpane:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(...) );

// add components to panel

for (...)
}
    for (...)
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add( textField );
    }
}

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
frame.add(scrollPane);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Can you give me a real example?

Comment: @KiryMeas, I did give you a real example. I gave you the skeleton code, so you just need to add your own loop conditions. I also gave you a link to the Swing tutorial which contains multiple working examples you can download and try. You learn by trying not by people typing in the code for you!

Comment: Thanks that a real teacher :]
I can do it yes I've tried your code
Here is the another problem 
How can I get Text from those Text field we've just created
Thank in advanced..